# How to add ssr to a vue-cli 3 project without webpack?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I created my project with:

```js
vue create my-project
```

But when my project was completed. I couldn't find the answer for "how to change my project to ssr without using webpack".

Does anyone has a sample project or tutorial?

Comment: https://github.com/eddyerburgh/vue-cli-ssr-example

Comment: I known it. But it still doesn't work in window [#2](https://github.com/eddyerburgh/vue-cli-ssr-example/issues/2)

Answer (score 0):

With NodeJS you can do:

```
// Step 1: Create a Vue instance
const Vue = require('vue')
const app = new Vue({
  template: `<div>Hello World</div>`
})

// Step 2: Create a renderer
const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer()

// Step 3: Render the Vue instance to HTML
renderer.renderToString(app, (err, html) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(html)
  // => <div data-server-rendered="true">Hello World</div>
})

// in 2.5.0+, returns a Promise if no callback is passed:
renderer.renderToString(app).then(html => {
  console.log(html)
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

Documentation:
https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/#installation